# ElasticsearchIntegrationTest cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: testing, elasticsearch

I'm trying to write an integration test, but I get "ElasticsearchIntegrationTest cannot be resolved to a type":

```
public class MyTest extends ElasticsearchIntegrationTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    ...
}

}
```

the dependency looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the value of the `elasticsearch.version` property in your pom.xml?

Comment: elasticsearch.version is set to 2.0.0